# Why am I losing video sync on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, graphics, visual-artifacts

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10.

When I want to search something my screen freezes and the video loses sync, with  something like this appearing:

[image: Ubuntu Error]

My System configuration is:
* Processor AMD Athlon LE-1640, ~2,7 GHz
* 2 GB RAM
* Video NVidia GeForce 6150SE nForce 410, integrated RAMDAC ~825 MB memory

Comment: would you try adding nomodeset and other options here? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Comment: And, would you please advise the make and model of the computer and its graphics adapter, and the make and model of monitor used if not a laptop? Please click on the grey _edit_ link above and to the left, and update your question to include that very useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the nvidia binary driver installed or are you using the open-source one's included by Ubuntu...  If it's the latter then go into Software Properties and click on the Additional Drivers tab and see if an Nvidia driver is detected for your system, this will help display issues...